# Navigation architecture: How to manage proper navigation without using clearTask as it is deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

While using navigation architecture as from [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116831650) , [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80338878) clearTask is deprecated.

My scenario is this: There are 2 screens Login and Registration, both have links to each other. So you can go to Registration from Login and also Login from Registration. **But on back Press App should be closed.**

It could simply be done by just adding clearTask to both actions as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nv_auth_phase"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_login">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_login"
        android:name="com.jobhook.ui.auth.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/nv_action_login_to_registration"
            app:clearTask="true"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_registration" />

    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_registration"
        android:name="com.jobhook.ui.auth.registration.RegistrationFragment"
        android:label="RegistrationFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_registration">


        <action
            android:id="@+id/nv_action_registration_to_login"
            app:clearTask="true"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_login" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

But as it was deprecated I have tried other solution like adding **popUpTo -> navigation graph's Id**, making **launchSingleTop to true in both actions**. Nothing seems to work in my scenario.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514758/how-to-clear-navigation-stack-after-navigating-to-another-fragment-in-android) also but didn't get a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use in your action next code

```
app:popUpTo="@+id/fragment_login"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

Comment: I still see up arrow in toolbar, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Set your NavHostFragment defaultNavHost value false,

```
<fragment
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="false"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    ... />
```

The app:defaultNavHost="true" attribute ensures that your NavHostFragment intercepts the system Back button. Note that only one NavHost can be the default. If you have multiple hosts in the same layout (two-pane layouts, for example), be sure to specify only one default NavHost.

Answer (score -2):

**Simple and effective solution:**

```
fun signOut(activity: Activity) = activity.finish()
```